# real values for a function

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functions

We know that $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c=0$ has two real solutions when $b^2-4ac \geq 0$

My question is, if we have a function

\begin{equation}
f(x)=\frac {D\ln((-0.5\sec x-1)/k)}{\ln a}-\frac {A|\sin(2x+\theta)|}{\sin x\sqrt{B+2A\cos(2x+\theta)}}=0 \nonumber 
\end{equation}

where $a,A,B,D,k$ and $\theta$ are cosntants.

1) How many real solutions $x$ has?

2) what values of $a,A,B,D,k$ and $\theta$, $x$ is unreal?

Comment: What is the relevance of the bit about the quadratic?

Comment: @RobertIsrael $x$ has a range where $\pi/2 \leq x \leq 2\pi/3$. which means I need to consider the solution in between that range only.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Sorry for the confusion. No relationship between to  a quadratic form. I want to explain my problem accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(x)$ is periodic in $x$, if there's one real solution there are infinitely many.  And you may be able to prove there are real solutions by considering limits at endpoints of intervals on which $f$ is real and continuous
and using the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: $x$ has a range where $\pi/2 \leq x \leq 2\pi/3$. which means I need to consider the solution in between that range only.

Comment: Why didn't you say so in the first place?

Comment: Anyway, you'll want to look at what happens to the first term as $x$ approaches $\pi/2$ from the right or $2\pi/3$ from the left.